# RewriteRule in htaccess fails, but it could be my host

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vhosts

I read that [Self Sabotage is Not asking for help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxhX8.jpg) so here I am.

So, I have a site...it's working great using WAMP. It's working great on my current host. But I need to switch to a new host and now it's failing. I figured it's a `.htaccess` issue but now I'm not sure. On my current host I have no `.htaccess` file and it works great. On my localhost server using WAMP I had the same thing as on my new host but I just disabled the `.htaccess` file, renaming it to `BAD.htaccess`, and the site still works great. This is why I think it's a server-side problem and I need some help. On my WAMP server in vhosts I disabled `+FollowSymLinks` for that "domain". On my current host I had no easy way to do that so it's just whatever they gave me, but it works.

I am currently with Ionos and have switched to GreenGeeks, who use cPanel. So far I haven't found a vhosts file to edit to remove `+FollowSymLinks`, if that is even the problem.

Maybe it can be accomplished with `.htaccess` and if so here is what I need to do. First my current `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^poems$ poems.php [R]
#RewriteRule ^poems/$ poems.php

RewriteRule ^collections$ collections/ [R]
RewriteRule ^collections/$ collections.php

RewriteRule ^poem$ poem/ [R]
RewriteRule ^poem/$ poem.php

RewriteRule ^poem/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z])$ poem.php?num=$1&poem=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^collection$ collection/ [R]
RewriteRule ^collection/$ collection.php

# RewriteRule ^poem/([0=9]+)$ indpoem.php?num=$1  [NC,L]
```

With the first two setups I can go to `example.com/poems` and it will redirect or rewrite to `example.com/poems.php` but still look like `example.com/poems`. Same with `collections`. On the new host those rewrite rules do rewrite it but the URL or URI shows `example.com/poems.php`, which I don't want per current SEO standards. Still, I could live with that.

However, when I get to the next level... `example.com/poem/#/poem-name` it fails on my new host. I do have a file called `poem.php` which it should rewrite to. In that file I use the following to get the `#` and name...

```
$URL = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

So I don't have to do a `_GET`.

As you can see I tried to do a `RewriteRule` to change it from the first to `example.com/poem?111&name`, but that just seems silly because on WAMP I don't have to do anything. I could try rewriting it to the same URL again, but I have a feeling that won't work. And if it does it will probably be `poem.php/#/name/`

Any thoughts on a server config I'm missing when using cPanel. I even tried doing

```
Options -FollowSymLinks
```

in my `.htaccess` file with no success.

Any help would be appreciated. My WAMP and the new host have all the most recent versions of Apache and PHP.

Comment: Try disabling `MultiViews`. That is often the culprit in such cases, where you have a partial overlap between the “fake” URL, and actually existing files.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. At least I think I did. Seems the only way to override those things is in .htaccess. So I uploaded a file with just Options -MultiViews and it didn't work. Then I uploaded my original file with that added. Still no luck. It's just odd it works on my WAMP and the other server with no .htaccess. On my WAMP, I even have FollowSymLInks disabled in the vhosts file, thinking that was causing a provlem. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Do your canonical URLs include a trailing slash? You are redirecting to append a trailing slash in your directives, but most of your examples omit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here...

- For the site to work *without* the `.htaccess` file at all (on your WAMP dev server and current host) then `MultiViews` (part of mod_negotiation) must have been enabled. It is `MultiViews` that "rewrites" `/foo` to `/foo.php`.
- If `MultiViews` is enabled then your current `.htaccess` file is essentially overridden since the `MultiViews` content-negotiation occurs before your mod_rewrite directives are processed so your `RewriteRule` *patterns* fail to match.
- `MultiViews` is disabled by default on Apache, it needs to be "explicitly" enabled. Unfortunately, some shared hosts do enable this in the server config (which causes more problems than it fixes - if you are not expecting it.)

> On the new host those rewrite rules do rewrite it but the URL or URI shows `example.com/poems.php`.
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^poems$ poems.php [R]
> ```

- Because MultiViews is disabled and your directives externally "redirect" `/poems` to `/poems.php`. There is no "rewrite" here. The `R` (`redirect`) flag triggers an external redirect.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^poem$ poem/ [R]
> RewriteRule ^poem/$ poem.php
> ```

- However, for `/poem` you are redirecting to `/poem/` (appending the trailing slash) but you have omitted the `L` flag so processing continues and the request is further rewritten to `/poem.php`. But because you have already triggered a `R`edirect, the request is "redirected" (not rewritten) to `/poem.php`, again exposing the `.php`.
- Redirects should nearly always include the `L` flag. In fact, all your rules should include the `L` flag for optimisation and to prevent accidental conflicts.
- Why are you redirecting to append the trailing slash (as if this is the preferred canonical URL)? You make no mention of this in your question text and only one of your examples includes a trailing slash on the URL as far as I can see? So, what is the preferred/canonical URL? What URL are you linking to? Incidentally, `MultiViews` will not append a trailing slash - so either this redirect is not required, or your site is not actually "working great" on WAMP / current host without the `.htaccess` file. (?) (Personally, I would *not* use a trailing slash.)

> ```
>  RewriteRule ^poem/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z])$ poem.php?num=$1&poem=$2 [NC,L]
>  :
>  $URL = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
> ```

- Your PHP script parses the requested URL-path (ie. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`), it is not referencing the query string. However, the above `RewriteRule` directive is rewriting to a query string - which would seem to be entirely superfluous ("silly" - as you suggest). Because you are not using the query string in your PHP script, the request still "works" when using MultiViews.
- According to your PHP script, you simply need to rewrite the request to `poem.php`, without a query string. (Which is what MultiViews does. Although, strictly speaking, MultiViews rewrites `/poem/123/name` to `/poem.php/123/name` - passing the additional URL-path as *path-info* to `poem.php`.)
- This regex only matches a single letter in the 3rd (name) path segment so it will fail to match a requested URL of the form `/poem/123/name`, so the request is not rewritten to `poem.php` and the request fails (with a 404 I suspect).
- This regex also does not match a trailing slash. (So, is the trailing slash really canonical?)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> ```

- These *conditions* are entirely superfluous where you have put them. `RewriteCond` directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows.

> ```
> Options -FollowSymLinks
> ```

- You need `FollowSymLinks` for mod_rewrite to work. Don't try to disable this. `FollowSymLinks` is actually the *default* Apache setting, so you only need to explicitly enable it (ie. `+FollowSymLinks`) in `.htaccess` if it has been disabled in the server config.

---

#### Solution

Personally, I would not use a trailing slash on the canonical URLs. (This is in line with most of your examples and the regex used in your rule.)

So, bringing the above points together:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# Canonical redirect to remove trailing slash (from non-directories)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [R,L]

# Internal rewrites to ".php"
RewriteRule ^poems$ poems.php [L]
RewriteRule ^collections$ collections.php [L]
RewriteRule ^poem(/\d+/[\w-]+)?$ poem.php [L]
RewriteRule ^collection$ collection.php [L]
```

On the other hand, if the canonical URL should include a trailing slash then change it accordingly:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# Canonical redirect to append trailing slash to "all" URLs
RewriteRule !/$ ${REQUEST_URI}/ [R,L]

# Internal rewrites to ".php"
RewriteRule ^poems/$ poems.php [L]
RewriteRule ^collections/$ collections.php [L]
RewriteRule ^poem/(\d+/[\w-]+/)?$ poem.php [L]
RewriteRule ^collection/$ collection.php [L]
```

If you have many such URLs/pages then you can make this entirely "generic" without having to explicitly name each URL/file. ie. "poems", "collections", etc.

---

Alternatively, you simply enable MultiViews and let mod_negotiation rewrite the URLs. However, you will not be able to canonicalise the trailing slash or validate the request before rewriting and MultiViews applies to *everything*, not just your `.php` files, so potentially creates duplicate content. If you need to do any specific rewriting, such are rewriting the query string then MultiViews is likely to conflict.

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Comment: Wow, thank you MrWhite. I think this answers all my questions. I tried contacting my host to see if there was some server side issue but they weren't very helpful. After reading your very detailed post it must be that MultiViews is disabled on the server. I did try adding that to the .htaccess file but did NOT remove all the Rewrites. I'll try that first. As for the /(slash) rewrites, that was what I'd done in the past and it seemed to work, maybe because I was rewriting to a query.

Comment: Originally in this I was not rewriting as a query just redirecting to the page and letting it do the work with _SERVER, I must not have removed that part when I posted my question. I know Multiviews is enabled in my vhosts on my WAMP, I'm guessing my old host had it enabled but the new one does not. So I'll first try that solution. So far I don't think it will affect my site but maybe when I add more it might so I'll also try your other solutions. Thank you so much. I spent hours searching here, youtube and the internet in general and could not find an answer this concise.